# How to refer to a single person of the general public?

Tags: word-request

I know "the general public" can be use both with a singular verb (when referred to as a group of a whole) and with a plural verb. But what if I want to refer to a single person, who is a member of the general public. Is there a word for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a comment under the question, the following example sentence was provided:

> This concept is clear to a scientist, but may be confusing to a ______ (member of the general public).

---

When referring to a non-scientist (or to anyone who doesn't belong to a specific area of expertise in discussion), the word [**layperson**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/layperson) (or *layman*) can be used.

> [Merriam-Webster]
>   : a member of the laity
>   // Of course, there is also a *layperson*'s theory that usually works.
>   — Julie Hinds, *Detroit Free Press*, "Twitter unleashes on Trump for Revolutionary War 'airport' flub," 5 July 2019
>   // In the spring of 2018 some of these *layperson* astronomers contacted Vanderburg and told him to check out HD 139139, a sunlike star roughly 350 light-years away.
>   — Adam Mann, *Scientific American*, "Astronomers Don't Know What to Make of This Incredibly Bizarre Star," 3 July 2019

From the further definition of [*laity*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/laity):

> **2** : the mass of the people as distinguished from those of a particular profession or those specially skilled
>   // writers who can interpret this wholeness both to their colleagues and the *laity*
>   — P. B. Sears

As such, a *layperson* is simply a member of the general public inasmuch as they don't belong to a particular group of trained people.

---

There is another word that's possible, but it's often used in an insulting fashion—even though it's actual definition is more neutral: [**plebe**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/plebe).

> **2 a** : one of the common people : PLEBIAN
>   // Once a proud and high-minded group, the new class could look up at the rich with a certain contempt and down at the plebes with compassion …
>   — Barbara Ehrenreich
>   **2 b** : an ordinary person who lacks the knowledge of an insider
>   // These guys may look like *plebes*, but they're veteran hackers.
>   — Davin Coburn
>   // The movie has its origins in Dave Stevens' 1982 graphic novel (comic book to us *plebes*), a knowing, exquisitely drawn valentine to aviation aces and 1930s Los Angeles.
>   — Ty Burr

Unless you are certain of how it will be taken, I would advise against using the word *plebe*, but I thought it should be included in the answer anyway, since it's still grammatically sound. And if it really is *the general public* that's being discussed rather than just somebody untrained, then *plebe* is actually more accurate.

Answer (score 0):

There are many colloquialisms for this that will be better understood than technical words. For example I would default to the phrase "the average Joe", if I were writing for the average Joe.